Как сделать так, чтобы исчезали фотографии в боте Телеграм, когда у меня есть Inline кнопки?
Как сделать так, чтобы исчезали фотографии в боте Телеграм?
Я создал простенького ТГ-бота для определения ID и Имени пользователя с Inline кнопками. Для красоты захотел добавить фотографию, что, естественно, получилось bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file), и да выше у меня есть обработчик и сам старт.
Суть вопроса такова: Как сделать так, чтобы фотография тоже исчезала(У МЕНЯ ЕСТЬ INLINE КНОПКИ)?
p.s. Сами сообщения у меня удаляются.
А, ну и сам код:
import telebot # Импортируем нужные библиотеки.
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN HERE, BUT NOT FOR U') # Подключаем бота.
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start']) # Делаем кнопку старт.
def handle_start(message): # Добавляем обработчика сообщения.
    file = open('hi.jpg', 'rb')

    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2) # Создаем клавиатуру на выбор ответа после сообщения "Привет! Хочешь узнать кое-что о себе?".
    but_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ДА!', callback_data = 'yes1')
    but_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton('НЕТ!', callback_data = 'no1')
    keyboard.add(but_yes, but_no)

    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Хочешь узнать кое-что о себе?', reply_markup = keyboard) # Посылаем сообщение.

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True) # Делаем еще одного обработчика, только на ответ на сообщения.
def handle_choice1(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'yes1':
            keyboard1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2) # Клавиатура на второе сообщение с ответом "ДА".
            but_id = types.InlineKeyboardButton('УЗНАТЬ ID', callback_data = 'id')
            but_nick = types.InlineKeyboardButton('УЗНАТЬ ИМЯ', callback_data = 'name')
            but_back = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ВЕРНУТЬСЯ', callback_data = 'back')
        
            keyboard1.add(but_id, but_nick, but_back)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = 'Выбери, что ты хотел бы узнать:', reply_markup = keyboard1)
        
        elif call.data == 'no1':
            keyboard2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2) # Клавиатура на второе сообщение с ответом "НЕТ".
            but_stay = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ОСТАТЬСЯ', callback_data = 'stay')
            but_leave = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ВЫЙТИ', callback_data = 'leave')
       

            keyboard2.add(but_stay, but_leave)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = 'Ты точно хочешь уйти?', reply_markup = keyboard2)
        
        elif call.data == 'id': 
            keyboard6 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2) # Клавиатура на сообщение с ответом на получение ID и кнопкой "ВЕРНУТЬСЯ".
            b11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ВЕРНУТЬСЯ', callback_data = 'back')
            keyboard6.add(b11)

            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = f'Хорошо, Твой ID: {call.from_user.id}', reply_markup = keyboard6)
        elif call.data == 'name':
            keyboard7 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2) # Клавиатура на сообщение с ответом на получение имени и кнопкой "ВЕРНУТЬСЯ".
            b110 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ВЕРНУТЬСЯ', callback_data = 'back')
            
            keyboard7.add(b110)

            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = f'Хорошо, тебя зовут: {call.from_user.first_name} {call.from_user.last_name}', reply_markup = keyboard7)
        elif call.data == 'back':
            keyboard5 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2) # Клавиатура на кнопку "ВЕРНУТЬСЯ", если есть необходимость.
            bb1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ДА!', callback_data = 'yes1')
            bb2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('НЕТ!', callback_data = 'no1')
            keyboard5.add(bb1, bb2)

            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = 'Хочешь узнать кое-что о себе?', reply_markup = keyboard5)
        
        
        elif call.data == 'stay':
            keyboard3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2) # Клавиатура на кнопку "ОСТАТЬСЯ".
            but_id1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ДА!', callback_data = 'yes1')
            but_nick1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('НЕТ!', callback_data = 'no1')
            
            keyboard3.add(but_id1, but_nick1)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = 'Ты вернулся в главное меню.\nХочешь узнать кое-что о себе?', reply_markup = keyboard3)
        elif call.data == 'leave':

            keyboard4 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2) # Клавиатура на кнопку "ВЫЙТИ".
            bbb1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ДА!', callback_data = 'yes1')
            b2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('НЕТ!', callback_data = 'no1')

            keyboard4.add(bbb1, b2)

            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = 'Хорошо, удачного дня. Если хочешь - возвращайся. Ты хочешь продолжить?', reply_markup = keyboard4)




bot.polling(non_stop = True)


сори, код криво отправился

Зачем исправили? теперь вообще уод не парвильный

А чуть подробней о логике "исчезания" ?

когда отправляешь сообщение, и чтобы бот потом, перед отправлением следующего, удалял старое сообщение и менял на новое, а тут как бы просто тоже самое, только полностью убрать фото, либо поменять это фото на след.сообщение с фото

Так в чем проблема? Запоминайте id нужного сообщения и удаляйте его
